# Is there a way to run a single test within the e2e tests in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, e2e-testing

I am trying to run a single set of a single set of tests within the e2e Kubernetes tests. I am quite confused as to how the tests are organized, is there a comprehensive list of all the tests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, the tests are placed at `./tests/e2e` path in the repository.

If the tests are written in go, they are mostly written using a standard **testing** library or **ginkgo** framework.

#### For running the tests written using standard **testing** package

1. Add the tags to a specific test at the start of your test file like,
   `// +build <my-test>`
2. Run the tests by specifying the tag name, `go test -v ./tests/e2e -tags <my-test>`

#### For running the tests written using **ginkgo**

1. `go test -ginkgo.dryRun ./tests/e2e/...` to list all the tests in the package.
2. `go test -ginkgo.focus "<regex>" ./tests/e2e/...` to run specific tests mentioned in the focus regex field.
3. `go test -ginkgo.skip "<regex>" ./tests/e2e/...` to skip the specific tests mentioned in the regex field

Answer (score 1):

If you have `e2e.test` binary, you can list all available test by setting following flag: `./e2e.test --ginkgo.DryRun`. Then if you want a single test, type: `./e2e.test --ginkgo.Focus="<name of your test>"`, pay attentention that all special characters in the test name must be escaped. For example, if you want run only conformance tests: `--ginkgo.Focus="\[Conformnce\]".`

Comment: Thanks! This might sound very silly but I can't figure out how to get a single tests to run. There is this test : [k8s.io] Downward API volume
/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:619
  should provide container's cpu request [Conformance] [Volume]
  /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/test/e2e/common/downwardapi_volume.go:181

Comment: how do I run that^^

Comment: It will be something like this: `./e2e.test --ginkgo.Focus="should provide container\'s cpu request"` . ginkgo.Focus is very similar to grep from linux system,  it will just execute all tests that match filter. So by setting filter  to match only one test, then this one test will be run.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, the right way of running particularly focused e2e tests is described officially here: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/e2e-tests.md

it would be something like this:

```
go run hack/e2e.go -- --test --test_args="--ginkgo.focus=${matching regex}"
```